# Magento 2 DOM validation exception when in developer mode

Tags: layout, template, xml, validation, ultimo

I'm running Magento 2.2.1 and Infortis Ultimo 2.5.1. When I'm in developer mode and I attempt to access a product page on the front end, I get the exception.

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'htmlTag': [facet 'enumeration'] The value '' is not an element of the set {'aside', 'dd', 'div', 'dl', 'fieldset', 'main', 'nav', 'header', 'footer', 'ol', 'p', 'section', 'table', 'tfoot', 'ul'}.
>   Line: 1159
>
> Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'htmlTag': '' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'htmlTagType'.
>   Line: 1159
>
> Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'htmlClass': [facet 'pattern'] The value '' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d-_]*(\s[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d-_]*)*'.
>   Line: 1159

This is because the `htmlTag` and `htmlClass` attributes in `app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` are not being set.

> ```
> <!-- Reset attributes of main containers -->
> <referenceContainer name="product.info.main" htmlTag="" htmlClass="" before="-" />
> <referenceContainer name="product.info.media" htmlTag="" htmlClass="" after="product.info.main" />
> ```

When switching to production mode the page renders correctly as expected with no errors. I've tried running the following commands:

```
php -d memory_limit=512M bin/magento cache:clean
php -d memory_limit=512M bin/magento cache:flush
php -d memory_limit=512M bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=512M bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -d memory_limit=512M bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Error is still appearing when in developer mode as described above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is due to use of <kbd>htmlTag</kbd>, <kbd>htmlClass</kbd> for referenceContainer. You must write as follows:

```
<!-- Reset attributes of main containers -->
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main"  />
<referenceContainer name="product.info.media" />
```

Please try without those html tags as you will not be needing them in referenceContainers. You can put those for containers and blocks.